# Uso e rapporto con l'originale della parola "gravido (a)"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Consultando un qualsiasi dizionario ([come qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gravido/)) vediamo che l'aggettivo *gravido* (per ovvi motivi usato al femminile) viene dal latino e identifica una donna o femmina di mammifero incinta.

Mi risulta che tale termine non sia però nella realtà usato per una donna, e che anzi abbia una connotazione semantica più "bassa", cosa che lo fa attribuire esclusivamente alla sfera animale.

Vorrei sapere se questo è vero e come sia avvenuto il lieve spostamento in quanto a sfera di afferenza dal latino all'italiano.

Comment: Cosa ti fa pensare che sia avvenuto dal latino all'italiano e non successivamente? Potrebbe benissimo essere uno "spostamento" degli ultimi secoli, ben successivo al passaggio della parola dal latino all'italiano.

Comment: @Bakuriu Giusto, allora dovremmo dire spostamento in generale tra l'uso originario (in riferimento all'etimologia probabilmente) e quello attuale.

Answer (score 7):

*Questo stato di tensione sarà gravido di conseguenze* è stile saggistico-giornalistico; il senso è quello proprio di *gravidanza*.

Per le donne è evitato per “delicatezza”: si dice (o si diceva) *è in stato interessante* o, più spiccio, *è incinta*. Di una vacca non si direbbe mai *è incinta*, ma solo *è gravida*.

Comment: Il limite diventa un pochino più sfumato, tuttavia, quando si parla di animali da compagnia. Molte persone considerano il loro cane/gatto/criceto/etc. come un membro della famiglia, e ho sentito spesso dire che una gatta fosse incinta.

Comment: @nico Giusta osservazione.

Comment: Però non mi è chiara la "delicatezza": perché un termine è più delicato dell'altro e quindi più adatto al mammifero umano?

Comment: @martina Perché l'altro non si usa per gli animali.

Comment: @egreg E così è un cane che si morde la coda, o sbaglio?

Comment: cfr. anche *sgravare*, adatto per le vacche ma mai per le persone.

Comment: @martina Certo; ma ci sono anche altri casi, come *cadavere* e *carcassa*.

Comment: @martina, comunque è sempre possibile parlare di *gravidanza* anche per le donne, i.e., 'Sì, la *gravidanza* di Carolina presenta alcune complicazioni'.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis Si, lo so, e direi che come sostantivo non ne esistono altri infatti...ma vorrei sapere com'è avvenuto il passaggio di registro lessicale tra il latino e l'italiano.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis *Gravidanza* non ha lo stesso impatto di “gravida”.

Comment: @egreg, se *cadavere* si usa per gli uomini e *carcassa* per gli animali, cosa si usa per i resti delle piante morte?

Comment: @martina, probabilmente 2000 anni fa la donna era considerata un mammifero da riproduzione, alla stregua degli altri mammiferi. Poi l'avvento del Cristianesimo deve aver influito sulla differente percezione della gravidanza degli animali rispetto a quella delle donne. I movimenti femministi hanno infine prodotto il cambio definitivo di 'registro'.

Comment: ... ma oggi che le donne non temono più di essere considerate mammiferi da riproduzione, iniziano di nuovo a dire, e lo sento spesso, 'sono gravida', in specie nelle conversazioni con altre donne. Però, come è detto nella answer, non è educato che un uomo, o una persona estranea, dica che una donna è *gravida*.